# How to determine field ID in CSJS runtime?

Tags: xpages

This is the scenario:

We have two fields on the Xpage to be filled from an Ajax call.
The return from the Ajax call is a json structure.
In old school web development we are doing this using prototype.js:

```
$H( json ).each(function(pair){
    try {
        $( pair.key ).value = pair.value  
    }
    catch(err) { }
});
```

Assumption here is that we have the fieldIDs equals the json keys.

```
{
    "fieldID1":"value1",
    "fieldID2":"value2"
}
```

Xpages CSJS needs to have the field ID placeholder present in the script to be able to convert to the actual ID that the field has on the Xpage:

```
$("#{id:fieldID1}").value = json.fieldID1;
$("#{id:fieldID2}").value = json.fieldID2;
```

How to determine the actual field ID in CSJS runtime using something like this:

```
$H( json ).each(function(pair){
    try {
        $("#{id:"+pair.key+"}").value = pair.value  
    }
    catch(err) { }
});
```

*Our actual form has +10 fields to be populated and depending on the circumstances the fields are dynamically "loaded" and therefor we have 2…n fields on the form to be populated by the ajax/json.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a CSJS implementation of *getComponent()* method from SSJS:

```
/**
 * getComponent
 *
 * CSJS implementation of SSJS's getComponent method
 *
 * @param serverId  ComponentId to search for
 * @param fromObj   DOM object to start with
 * @author Sven Hasselbach
 * @version 0.3
 */
function getComponent( serverId, fromObj ){

    var found = false;
    var obj = fromObj;
    var id = "";

    while( obj ){
        try{
            id = obj.id.split(":").pop();
        }catch(e){}

        if( id == serverId )
            return obj;

        ret = findComponent( serverId, obj );
        if( ret )
            return ret;

        obj = obj.parentNode;
    }

}

/**
 * findComponent
 * 
 * searches the component tree for a specific
 * server id
 */
function findComponent( searchId, parentNode ){
    var obj;
    var id = "";

    if( parentNode == null )
        return;

    if( parentNode.hasChildNodes() == false )
        return;

    for( p in parentNode.childNodes ){
        obj = parentNode.childNodes[p];
        try{
            id = obj.id.split(":").pop();

            if( id == searchId )
                return obj;

            ret = findComponent( searchId, obj );
            if( ret )
                return ret;

        }catch(e){}
    }
}
```

This allows you to search in the component tree for a specific server id.
To use it you have to define a starting component first, because the tree is searched from a node to the top.

To get your starting node:

```
var obj = XSP.getElementById( "view:_id1:layoutMain:callbackMiddle:dataViewAllReportsByStatus:1_sumLink" );
```

Then search for another component *layoutLeft* f.e.:

```
var ret = getComponent("layoutLeft", obj );
alert( ret.id )
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, the problem is that the XPage does not know the id when it is served to the browser. It is calculated by using the pair.key. Marky Roden wrote a couple of very good articles on this where I think you may find the solution that fits you. See:

http://xomino.com/2012/01/26/using-jquery-selectors-in-xpages/

and

http://xomino.com/2012/02/02/jquery-selector-function-for-xpages-xidinputtext1/

HTH ;-)

/John

Comment: Yep, you need to use getClientId("controlname") in the SSJS to get the right id. In jQuery you might need to escape the : in the id eventually (dojo.byId works)

Comment: My problem is to determine the ID of the component in runtime not in designtime. Is it possible? The examples by Marky is how to determine the ID of the component using jQuery but it is still in designtime since the Id of the component must be known for Xpages to be able to convert it…

Comment: The first link I put in the answer gives you some good background on the problem - and some ideas to solutions. One idea is to use a classname that contains the fieldname. Then you can use jQuery at runtime to find the field using the classname instead. The other idea could be to build a "hashmap" at load time with the field names and the "true" identifiers using the #{...} syntax. Then you would use the field name as a key to find the real id in this "table"... Not necessarily elegant - but it could work ;-)  /John